# There is no implicit reference conversion from table to ITableEntity in Azure Function

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-table-storage, azure-tablequery

I am writing my first Azure Function and Azure table code. I am getting issue when I write `Get` query function. I have the following code that would try to get all the jobs from the table.

```
public static class GetJobStatus
{
    [FunctionName("GetJobStatus")]
    public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
        [Table("JobTable")] CloudTable jobTable,
        ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation("Get job status.");

        string jobId = req.Query["jobid"];

        TableQuery<JobTable> query = new TableQuery<JobTable>();
        var segment = await jobTable.ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync(query, null);
        var data = segment.Select(JobExtension.ToJob);

        return new OkObjectResult("");
    }
}
```

But, I get compile time errors on these statements:

```
TableQuery<JobTable> query = new TableQuery<JobTable>();
var segment = await jobTable.ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync(query, null);
```

I am trying to paste the actual error messages that appear on hover:
[image]
and, get the following on the `ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync` method
[image]

My `JobTable` inherits from `ITableEntity` (Azure.Data.Tables):

```
public class JobTable : ITableEntity
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedTime { get; set; }
    public JobRequest Request { get; set; }

    //ITableEntity Members
    public virtual string PartitionKey { get; set; } = "Job";
    public virtual string RowKey { get => Id; set => Id = value; }
    public DateTimeOffset? Timestamp { get; set; }
    public ETag ETag { get; set; }
}
```

I have the following nuget packages installed:
[image]

I was trying to implement from this [article](https://labs.sogeti.com/create-webapi-with-azure-functions-azure-table-storage-part-1-development/), but it uses older nuget packages, and I was getting trouble.

**Update #1:**

As per the suggestions from `Gaurav Mantri`, to be consistent, I have removed `Azure.Data.Tables` and started using `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table`. That fixed the compile time errors. But now I get the following runtime error:

```
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'GetJobStatus'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Tables: Can't bind Table to type 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.CloudTable'.
```

**Update #2:**

I couldn't make it work, so I reverted all my code and references to use `Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table` as described in the article I was referncing. Everything works as expected now. But, I still would like to see how I can use the newer libraries. For the original issue that was receiving, it was solved by Gaurav's suggestion so I will accept the answer for now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are running into this issue is because you are using two different SDKs - `Azure.Data.Tables` and `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table`.

Your `JobTable` entity implements `ITableEntity` from `Azure.Data.Tables` and you are using that with your `CloudTable` from `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table`.

Can you try by removing `Azure.Data.Tables` package and just use `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table`?

Comment: Great catch. I removed `Azure.Data.Tables` package and also updated `JobTable` to use `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table` and but `JobTable` entity now inherits from `TableEntity`. The code compiles but gives a runtime error:
`The 'GetJobStatus' function is in error: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'GetJobStatus'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Tables: Can't bind Table to type 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.CloudTable'.`

Comment: You can try to do it the other way around i.e. use Azure.Data.Tables. Essentially the idea is to use just one SDK.

Comment: When I try to do the other way, I can't use `CloudTable` and `TableQuery` anymore. I think I have to use `TableClient` instead. I don't see any examples of how to use `TableClient` in my code specially Azure Functions. Appreciate any leads.